# Use array object from javascript use-api into javascript with sightly

Tags: javascript, arrays, aem, sightly

I have a javascript use-api file that returns an array. **It's important to know that this js is used in other html, that's why i can't put the code on the html**
Something like this (`myfile.js`):

```
"use strict";

var global = this;

use(function() {
    var myArray = [];
    //something to fill the array with custom objects and inner arrays
    return myArray;
});
```

Then in my html i have some code but the most important is that i need to use this array in javascript but i can't figure out how to do it because if i use the `context='scriptString'` or `context='scriptToken'` it doesn't work and i cant use the array.

This is the code:

```
<div data-sly-use.test="myfile.js">
   <!-- some html irrelevant code -->

   <script type='text/javascript'>
       //this returns a flat string representation of the first level of the array
       var a = '${test @context='scriptString'}';
       //this give an error in the code
       var b = ${test @context='scriptString'};
       //this returns empty
       var c = '${test @context='scriptToken'}';
   </script>
</div>
```

Is there a way to use this array (**without modifying `myfile.js` file)**

Comment: the `test` is for this question only.. in my code i have a different name. but i don't think that this will fixit.. anyway i will try it.

Comment: I realized that wouldn't fix it, so i erased the comment.

Comment: But maybe try using double quotes... "${test @context='scriptString'}"

Comment: or try ${test[0]} for the first item in the array

Comment: that `${test[0]}` gives the first letter of the string and that's the problem.. the `'${test @context='scriptString'}'`returns a string

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a JS object, array in this case, that you want to use on both the server-side and the client-side. You build it server-side using the Use-API and use it however you need to in the sightly templates, then you're trying to add the same object to a `<script>` tag so that the client can also use it. Is this correct? If so then try one of these, if you haven't already

```
<div data-sly-use.test="myfile.js">
<!-- some html irrelevant code -->

 <script type='text/javascript'>
     //scriptToken context, no quotation marks
     var b = ${test @context='scriptString'};
     //unsafe context, hope you trust the source of this object!
     var c = ${test @context='unsafe'};
 </script>
</div>
```

---

Hoever, **if you do not need the JS object on the server-side** then there's no need ot use the Use-API. Just create a separate sightly file which adds the javascript to the page, and include it in the sightly files that need it.

`/apps/path/to/shared/myfile.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var global = this;

  var myArray = [];
  //something to fill the array with custom objects and inner arrays
  //etc.
 </script>
```

Then the templates that need that JS simply include it

```
<div>
  <!-- some html irrelevant code -->
  <sly data-sly-include="path/to/shared/myfile.html"></sly>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest if you want to put variables into the array you just use the following (and stick with purely javascript:

```
   <div data-sly-use.test="myfile.js">

   <script type='text/javascript'>    

    var a = myArray[n];

   </script>

</div>
```

Where n is equal to the object number in the array that you want to return the value of.

This way you have no need to edit the javascript file and it makes everything much more simple!

Comment: I have clarify that i can't place the javascript code inside the html, this js is being used by another html (components).

Comment: @Phoenix_uy Okay I have edited my answer. Also, it shouldn't interfere with any other javascript unless you are using the same variables elsewhere.

Comment: What you put is nothing to do with my question... i'm trying to "extract" an array that `myfile.js` returns using the `use-api`. I know how to put variables into the array but that's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

I just did tests myself and it worked fine.  Here's what I did.
Just a note, this is on AEM 6.1 (without SP1)

test.html:

```
<div data-sly-use.test="test.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var test = [${test @context="scriptString"}];       
    </script>
    This is a TEST!
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

test.js:

```
"use strict";

use(["/libs/wcm/foundation/components/utils/AuthoringUtils.js"], function (AuthoringUtils) {

    return [0,1,2,3,4,5];

});
```

and this is the resulting html

```
<div class="test">    
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var test = [0,1,2,3,4,5];       
    </script>
    This is a TEST!
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be warned though, after deeper testing, you cannot return an array of complex objects, I just tried it, it will put all values in a single array instead.  Also, I don't think it's a good idea to return directly an array in an api-use, it's better to return an object which you would add your values in properties.  That way, if you have components that share the same script, you can add a new property specific to a component.  Here I would suggest having an "object.json" which you could then reparse in your main script.